# ¿Como obtener la ruta completa de un nodo seleccionado de treelist DevExpress?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, devexpress

Tengo un treeList (DevExpress) y quiero obtener en un label la ruta completa de un nodo seleccionado. Por ejemplo: **Nodo_Padre\Nodo_Hijo\Nodo_Nieto ...** , algo como el fullpath de treeview de Windows forms nativo.

[image: TreeList]

**Ruta**: Dxperience 12.2 Demos\WinForms\XtraTreeList

Seria la ruta en el nodo seleccionado.

¿Como obtener la ruta completa del nodo seleccionado?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes navegar desde el nodo hijo seleccionado hasta su nodo padre usando la propiedad `ParentNode`. Debes tener en cuenta que cuando llegues al nodo del nivel superior (el que no tiene padre) la propiedad `ParentNode` devolverá valor `Null`. Por lo tanto con un simple bucle consultando los padres hasta dar con null puedes obtener lo que buscas.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, creí que había un método() mas rápido, bueno la solución es con bucle. Tediosos pero funciona.